# create PDF with Unicode using jsPDF

Tags: javascript, angular, unicode, jspdf

I want save a PDF with Sinhala unicode. but when try to convent data gives me junk data something like this "Ê¶±Ê°ÀoÒ". If I cannot do this in jsPDF suggest me a another way but I do not want to use a screenshot like html2canvas.

```
let doc = new jsPDF('landscape'); 
doc.text(15, 30, 'ස්තුතියි');
doc.save("new.pdf");
```

Comment: You need add Iskole Potha or any other Sinhala Unicode Font. You can use https://peckconsulting.s3.amazonaws.com/fontconverter/fontconverter.html to convert your font file into JS file then it should work. Even if this is a working solution upto some point, some joint letters are still not rendered well.